# 5 year old. Still needs us to fall asleep

Tags: sleep, sleep-training

We never successfully got our child to fall asleep on their own. We would always have to be in the room. Now she's five and still needs us in the room. We need to either hold her hand or run her back.

What can we do to have her fall asleep on her own?

I've looked at other related posts such as:

- [Our 4 year old won't fall asleep until 11pm](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/5451/1922)
- [My 8 year old son won't fall asleep](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/6735/1922)

It's not the same as those questions. My daughter requires someone to sit with them before falling asleep.  We can't leave the room.  We tried to do the timing thing with her.  Leave the room for 1 minute, then 2, then 3, etc. but she is really resistant to it. She won't calm down. I tried to ask her why she gets upset when we leave and she just says that she needs us to rub her back or hold her hand.  We have to do this every night so it is quite exhausting.

Comment: have you read the top 3 posts in the Related sidebar to the right?

Comment: @RoryAlsop. I just edited my question to take those into account.

Comment: Question about the timing thing, how long did you try it? 5 days? 2 weeks? How many times have you tried it? Twice, each time lasting only a few days, etc...?

Comment: We've been trying for about a week. However on the hard days we give in and sit next to her.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation.  Good or bad this is what I did.  Lord I know some people are going to be giving me the hairy eyeball!
I allowed my 5 year old to use his Nabi tablet for 30 mind in his bed BUT only if he went to sleep on his own afterward. he liked the back rub and story thing too.
I also asked the pediatrician about Melatonin. Which is all natural and something our bodies make naturally.  She said to give it a try. So I used 1mg of Melatonin, and a Nabi.  A month later got rid of Melatonin.  he still likes Nabi 6 now but he falls asleep in 15-20 minutes playing or reading on there.
Hairy eyeballs be damned! It worked!  LoL